# How manage orientation of other applications from my app?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I see this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate&hl=en
that can set the orientation of every app at start.
how could I set the orientation of another app? I have not been able to find nothing about this. Thanks!
P.D Sorry for my english :)